# RxPermission causes Internal Error in release mode

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rxpermissions

I use RxPermission library to handle runtime permissions easily,

In my app I ask for location:

```
 rxPermissions
                .request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (granted) {
                        boolean gpsEnabled, networkEnabled;

                        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                            if (gpsEnabled && locationListenerGPS != null) {

                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListenerGPS);
                            }

                            if (networkEnabled && locationListenerNetwork != null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListenerNetwork);
                            }

                        }


                    } else {
                        Log.d("Access not granted", "no location");
                    }
                });
```

When I open the debug-apk It works perfect but when I try to open release apk it crashes with this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.magis.icbc, PID: 19522
>                                                      java.lang.InternalError
>                                                          at d.c.d.b.s.a(UnsafeAccess.java:115)
>                                                          at d.c.d.b.r.(SpscArrayQueue.java:42)
>                                                          at d.c.a.d$c.(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:129)
>                                                          at d.c.a.d.a(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:82)
>                                                          at d.c.a.d.a(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>                                                          at d.d.a(Observable.java:10142)
>                                                          at d.c.a.k$e.a(OperatorMerge.java:248)
>                                                          at d.c.a.k$e.b(OperatorMerge.java:148)
>                                                          at d.c.a.h$a.b(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
>                                                          at d.c.a.k$e.a(OperatorMerge.java:511)
>                                                          at d.c.a.k$e.a(OperatorMerge.java:466)
>                                                          at d.c.a.k$e.a(OperatorMerge.java:244)
>                                                          at d.c.a.k$e.b(OperatorMerge.java:148)
>                                                          at d.c.a.e$a.a(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:76)
>                                                          at d.c.a.e$a.a(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:58)
>                                                          at d.i.a(Subscriber.java:211)
>                                                          at d.c.a.e.a(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:32)
>                                                          at d.c.a.e.a(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:24)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>                                                          at d.d.a(Observable.java:10142)
>                                                          at d.c.a.h.a(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
>                                                          at d.c.a.h.a(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>                                                          at d.d.a(Observable.java:10142)
>                                                          at d.c.a.h.a(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
>                                                          at d.c.a.h.a(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>                                                          at d.c.a.g.a(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>                                                          at d.d.a(Observable.java:10238)
>                                                          at d.d.b(Observable.java:10205)
>                                                          at d.d.a(Observable.java:10010)
>                                                          at com.magis.icbc.ui.activities.SplashActivity.n(SplashActivity.java:222)
>                                                          at com.magis.icbc.ui.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:173)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field producerIndex in class
>   Ld/c/d/b/r; (declaration of 'd.c.d.b.r' appears in
>   /data/app/com.magis.icbc-1/base.apk)
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
>                                                          at d.c.d.b.s.a(UnsafeAccess.java:112)

eaxctly at this line  `.subscribe(granted -> {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have one of those devices which rename fields and break reflection in addition to seemingly providing Unsafe access. Try disabling this old RxJava feature by setting the `rx.unsafe-disable` system property to `true` before RxJava could get initialized.